# Can I safely disable DLCs in Oldrim if they have already been started?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Yesterday I bought the Dragonborn DLC for Oldrim on PC. I don't like it that much at the moment and would just prefer to have Dawnguard/Hearthfire. Sure, I could just not play any of those DB quests and not visit Solsteim, but I played it for a bit yesterday and have a few quests from DB in my journal, I would prefer that things are cleaner.

Seeing there are no locations within Skyrim which DB adds, would it be possible to just untick the DB DLC from the Skyrim menu and load a previous pre-DB game?

Comment: With mods this is most unwise. I don't see why it would not be unwise with official DLC.

Comment: According to Bethesda it's fine to disable it on the Xbox, as long as you don't then try to use those DLC saves. https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/18328/~/how-do-i-remove-the-dragonborn-dlc-from-my-xbox-360%3F

Comment: If you use any other mods and your load order changes because you removed a DLC, it might cause problems on an existing save. Which is why I said unwise to do so. But YMMV. Which is why I am not posting an answer and just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I tried this and have now played for several hours with no problem. The trick is to load a save that was created pre-DB install. So what works for [Xbox](https://help.bethesda.net/app/answers/detail/a_id/18328/%7E/how-do-i-remove-the-dragonborn-dlc-from-my-xbox-360%3F) also works for PC in this case.